# Apollo Client and Update Forms

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I was wondering if anyone has a good example of an update form using Apollo Client and the new query and mutation components. By update I mean:

- Populate form values with query results
- Update the component state (or apollo-link-state?) when the input is edited.
- On submission update the state (or apollo-link-state?)

I'm struggling with it right now and I'm wondering what the best way to build it would be. Should I be using Apollo-link-state to store the form state? If not, I can't find a way to map the props from the query component into component state object without using the query HOC. Any examples would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the state doesn't need to be accessed by other parts of your app, `apollo-link-state` is probably overkill -- regular component state will do just fine. Just create a component like you would when using the HOC:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fieldA = props.myQuery.fieldA
      fieldB = props.myQuery.fieldB
    }

    render () {
      // your form fields here
    }
  }
}
```

You can then just do:

```
<Query>
  {({data, loading})=>(
    if (loading || error) return null
    <MyComponent myQuery={data.myQuery}>
  )}
</Query>
```

Comment: ok, this is what I've been doing. You put the mutation inside of MyComponent right?

Comment: Yes, although you could also pass down those values too